# duplicating rows through multiple tables(new id/foreign key) with some column modifications

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, plsql

The basic concepts is to duplicate rows in table1 where id between for example 100..10000, 
modify some of the column data then insert with a new id:

Table2 referencing to table1.id with foreign key, table3 referencing to table2.id with foreign key
.... and tableX referencing to tableX-1.id with foreign key. 
I also have the modificate some of the table2..tableX data.

I started to think about writing nested loops; for the first 3 table, it looks like this (in plsql), maybe it should work:

```
declare
table1_row  table1%rowtype;
table2_row  table2%rowtype;
table3_row  table3%rowtype;
begin
  for t1 in(select * from table1 
  where id between 100 and 10000)
  loop
    table1_row:=t1;
    table1_row.id:=tableseq.nextval;
    table1_row.col1:='asdf';
    table1_row.col4:='xxx';
    insert into table1 values table1_row;

    for t2 in(select * from table2 
    where foreign_key_id =t1.id)
    loop
        table2_row:=t2;
        table2_row.id:=tableseq.nextval;
        table2_row.foreign_key_id:=table1_row.id;
        table2_row.col3:='gfdgf';
        insert into table2 values table2_row;

        for t3 in(select * from table3 
        where foreign_key_id =t2.id)
        loop
            table3_row:=t3;
            table3_row.id:=tableseq.nextval;
            table3_row.foreign_key_id:=table2_row.id;
            table3_row.col1:='gdfgdg';
            insert into table3 values table3_row;        
        end loop;     
    end loop;       
  end loop;
end;
```

Any better solutions? With about 10-20nested loops, it looks awful :(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database and which version ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use an insert statement with several subqueries to clean this up.  Here is a simpler example but I believe you can extrapolate for your specific case:

```
insert into table1
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
values
select 'asdf',
       (select table2_data --whatever data from this table you want
          from table2
         where foreign_key_id =table1.id),
       (select table3_data --whatever data from this table you want
          from table3
         where foreign_key_id =table1.id),
       'xxx',
       table1.col5
  from table1
 where table1.id between 100 and 10000
```

Note, your id column should be set up as an Auto_increment primary key so you shouldn't need it as part of your insert statement.  Also, I added "table1.col5" as an example of how to use the same data from the existing row in your duplicated row (as I'm assuming some data you want to be duplicated).